# How to make a regex that works in multi line mode also work in single line in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following string fragment:

```
var someInput = ..... +
"admin-state : up" +
"opr-state/tx-rate-ds : up :32093" +
"cur-op-mode : g993-2-8d" +
"tx-rate-us : 5048" +
"tx-rate-ds : 32093" +
"noise-margin-down : 204" +
"noise-margin-up : 165" +
"actual-tps-tc-mode : ptm" +
"overrule-state : not-created" +
.....;
```

I am trying to extract the three sections of the line:

"opr-state/tx-rate-ds : up :32093"

I am using [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to try out my expressions. And to get each of the values I came up with these:

```
@"(?<paramName>opr-.[^\s]*)" // Gets "opr-state/tx-rate-ds"  
@"opr.*:\s*(?<middle>.*(?=:))" // Gets "up"  
@"opr.*:\s*.*:(?<value>[\d]*)" // Gets 32093
```

The problem is that it works considering each line in the input independently but, I am getting the input as a single string which basically is as if I am running the regex in **single line mode** on the tester so the results I get in the application are as follows:

```
@"(?<paramName>opr-.[^\s]*)" // Gets "opr-state/tx-rate-ds"  
@"opr.*:\s*(?<middle>.*(?=:))" // Gets everything from the first ": up" until the last ":" before "not-created"   
@"opr.*:\s*.*:(?<value>[\d]*)" // Gets 32093
```

So trying to phrase what I want this expression to do would be something like:

> In a single string, find whatever is between `opr.*:\s*` and the
>   following colon

So far I've tried changing the options on the Match method to run it as Singleline and changing the expression to  `opr.*:\s*(?<middle>[^:])` but none of those have worked.

I really suck at regular expressions, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using this regex: [`(?<paramName>opr.*?)\s*:\s*(?<middle>[^:]*?)\s*:\s*(?<value>\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/Tester?p=(%3f%3cparamName%3eopr.*%3f)%5cs*%3a%5cs*(%3f%3cmiddle%3e%5b%5e%3a%5d*%3f)%5cs*%3a%5cs*(%3f%3cvalue%3e%5cd%2b)&i=opr-state%2ftx-rate-ds+%3a+up+%3a32093).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problen you're facing is because the regex engine is greedy by default. Any quantifier, such as `*`, `?`, or `{n,m}` will try to match as much as it can, only backtracking if the rest of the pattern doesn't match. I find this article quite useful to understand the internals:
[Watch Out for The Greediness!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy).

**Solution:**
Use *lazy* quantifiers adding an extra `?` immediately afterwards. Examples:

- `.*?`
- `\s+?`
- `[a-z]{5,}?`

These will try to match as less as they can, only consuming more characters when the engine backtracks.

In your case, it works if you modify the expression to `opr.*?:\s*(?<middle>[^:]+)`

**However**, let's try a different approach. In regular expressions, it helps to be as specific as you can. If you look at it from another angle, all you're trying to match in every *token* are characters except colons (`:`) or, even better, anything except colons and whitespace.

Code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<paramName>  opr-[^\s:]+  )  # literal `opr-` followed by any chars except whitespace or `:`
                          \s*:\s*                        # separator: literal `:` optionally surrounded by any number of whitespace chars
                          (?<middle>  [^\s:]+  )         # any chars except whitespace or `:`
                          \s*:\s*                        # separator
                          (?<value>  \d+  )              # 1 or more digits (an integer)
                         "
                       , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Compiled);

foreach (Match ItemMatch in regex.Matches(someInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", 
                      ItemMatch.Groups["paramName"].Value,
                      ItemMatch.Groups["middle"].Value, 
                      ItemMatch.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

*Notice I used `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` to ignore spaces in the pattern, and to allow the comments.

The `[^\s:]+` is a `character class` to match all characters, except:

- `\s` whitespace
- `:` a literal colon

Using that construct, you don't need to worry about *greediness*.

Online test: [Check the code here](http://rextester.com/HZS60130)

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy repetition:

```
@"opr.*?:\s*(?<middle>.*?(?=:))"
```

`.*` tries to match as many characters as possible. `.*?` will make it match only as little as it needs. And given that you have set clear boundaries (`:`), little is just enough.

[See it in action](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=opr.*%3f%3a%5cs*(%3f%3cmiddle%3e.*%3f(%3f%3d%3a))&i=admin-state+%3a+upopr-state%2ftx-rate-ds+%3a+up+%3a32093cur-op-mode+%3a+g993-2-8dtx-rate-us+%3a+5048tx-rate-ds+%3a+32093noise-margin-down+%3a+204noise-margin-up+%3a+165actual-tps-tc-mode+%3a+ptmoverrule-state+%3a+not-created)